# Powershell: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: powershell

I am using simple url connection. The telnet command works for the URL,so url is correct but still its giving this exception

```
 Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
 CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [],MethodInvocationException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebException
```

I am using below code-

```
 [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
  $url ='https://url:port/rest/eventsc=abc&ec=xyz&ft=[please take necessary actions]'
  $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
  $wc.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic YWN1c3VzZXI6ODg3SGd2NDY=")
  $wc.DownloadString($url)
```

Comment: If you have access to the servers access logs you can easily look up there what url your client tries to retrieve.

Comment: @Gerald The url seems correct, can there be any other reason like need a need of ssl certificate while making connection or changing any other net settings through script